# SpriteKit place SKShapeNode in center of scene

Tags: sprite-kit, swift, skshapenode

I have an ellipse that I want to draw in the center of the scene

```
 let center = (view.scene.position.x, view.scene.position.y)
 let size = (view.scene.frame.size.width * 0.7, view.scene.frame.size.height * 0.7)
 let ellipse = SKShapeNode (ellipseInRect: CGRectMake(center.0, center.1, size.0, size.1))
 ellipse.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
 ellipse.position = CGPointMake(center)
 self.addChild(ellipse)
```

But it shows up in the scene like:

[image: myscene]

How do I position this in the center of the scene?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using

```
let ellipse = SKShapeNode (ellipseInRect: CGRectMake(center.0, center.1, size.0, size.1))
```

use

```
let ellipse = SKShapeNode (ellipseOfSize: CGSizeMake(size.0, size.1))
```

And center the sprite around

```
let center = (CGRectGetMidX(view.scene.frame), CGRectGetMidY(view.scene.frame))
```